# How did I lose 10 reputation points yesterday?

Tags: support, reputation

I just lost 10 reputation points and in my history, all it says was "user was removed". Can someone explain?

Comment: Related: http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/q/1289/2451 and http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/126470

Answer (score 4):

It has already been addressed in the [mother meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/126471/205334). Some guy has voted your answer and you gained a +10 for that. Now, the buddy has removed his account and his votes have been revoked. Whatever he had voted (as a member of this site), will be reversed (once he removes his account), which means *not only you*, but anyone who were voted by him will be affected.

This is a pretty interesting scheme. Even for an user who has cast more than 5000 votes, once he removes his account, all those votes are *gone*...

Comment: Note: "Highly active" users' votes are **not** removed if their accounts are deleted (well, if the deletion occurs by request of the user in question). See [this meta post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/156520). I don't know if "highly active" means lots of rep, lots of generic activity, or lots of voting.

Comment: @ChrisWhite: Okay then... Except 20k+ users ;-)

Comment: -1 for the casual sexism

Comment: @EnergyNumbers: Umm... For what? *Can't really understand your point here* o_O

Comment: @CrazyBuddy, I think what EnergyNumbers means is your referenced to "Some guy" rather than "someone" or "some person".